# Get the lock status of an account on Solaris

Tags: sudo, solaris, accounts, lock

I do not have root privileges.

I wish to get the lock status of a given account say `mwss`

I'm on Sun Solaris

```
uname -a
SunOS myhost 5.11 11.4.27.82.1 sun4v sparc sun4v
```

Below is the output from shadow file.

```
sudo grep dias /etc/shadow

mwss:*AL*$5$rounds=10000$yX8/zAfl$DH9du8FiUDxfTV7jVWu7rhET9AUFG3.yrBzgoWXtns8:18397::::::5270551
```

From the above how can we determine if account mwss is locked or not ? Any other solutions will also be appreciated.

Comment: *I do not have root privileges.*  Yes you do - you're reading `/etc/shadow`, which requires root privileges.

Comment: Fine … but the question remains …. how do I determine if it is locked or unlocked ? @AndrewHenle